# How to reuse java code block

Tags: java

I want to reuse block of java code.

This is full code block:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        // begin of different part  
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Table.class);
        if(filters!=null)
            createFilter(criteria, filters, null,null);                 
        long count=(long)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
        this.setRowCount((int) count);
        // end of different part

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null)
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And I need to use blocks:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
```

and

```
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null)
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

many times in different classes. But the middle part will be different. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is the full code a method? The method definition line seems to be missing. And is that a method you would like to implement in many different classes? But rather than repeating all the code only write the code marked as different in the classes and reuse the rest? Perhaps each class implements an interface that defines this method?

Comment: You should change your way of thinking upside down and use the solution provided by @ManuelSeiche. By *upside down* I mean that you should not think about "reusing parts of code", but about making the *other* part of your code variable - exactly as Manuel suggests.

Comment: I suggest reading the [Template method design patten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and see it in use in this [Java template method example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/java/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make an example from a stripped down version of your code, so that it works without Hibernate.

Original code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int rowCount;

    public void doStuff() {
        Object session = new Object();

        try {
            session.getClass();  // represents session.getTransaction();

            // begin of different part
            String s = session.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
            this.setRowCount(5);
            // end of different part

            session.getClass();  // represents commit
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Do some cleanup");
        }
    }

    public void setRowCount(int count) {
        rowCount = count;
    }
}
```

This would be called from some other place as:

```
MyCLass obj = new MyClass();
obj.doStuff();
```

Now for the changes. I'm going to use lambda expressions plus define an `interface` with the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`. This is because the `apply` method in the interface will return an `Exception`. The standard functional interfaces in Java 8 don't support that.

First the new interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunction {
    void apply(Object session, MyClass self) throws Exception;
}
```

Now the changes in the original code:

change from

```
    public void doStuff() {
```

to

```
    public void doStuff(MyFunction func) {
```

Remove the part labelled different code and replace it with:

```
    func.apply(session, this);
```

And the calling from:

```
obj.doStuff();
```

to

```
obj.doStuff((session, self) -> {
    String s = session.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    self.setRowCount(5);
});
```

---

If Java 8 is not an option, remove `@FunctionalInterface` in the interface. Then call `doStuff()` like this:

```
obj.doStuff(new MyFunction() {
    @Override
    public void apply(Object session, MyClass self) throws Exception {
        String s = session.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        self.setRowCount(5);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's almost what I need, but I need to support java 7 :(

Comment: Is there any way to use different classes for self?

Comment: If you use an interface instead, and let each class implement that interface.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example using Runnable as functional interface. If you need to pass params, you could also write your own.

*To be clean, you could also write your own functional interface, because Runnable is normally used when it's about Threading.*

```
public class RunnableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableExample example = new RunnableExample();
        example.general(() -> {
            System.out.println("specificA");
        });
        example.general(() -> {
            System.out.println("specificB");
        });
    }

    public void general(Runnable specific) {
        System.out.println("general start");
        specific.run();
        System.out.println("general end");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
general start
specificA
general end
general start
specificB
general end
```

Comment: >>But I don't see from your example that you have to use your Session inside the middle part.

// begin of different part  
Criteria criteria=**bold**session**bold**.createCriteria(Table.class);

Comment: The try and catch block is missing in the example.

Comment: My example is just a hint :-) Create your own interface use it as param and throw Exceptions on run() or whatever you call your Method.

Replace System.out.println("general start"); with your top-block and System.out.println("general end"); with your bottom-block

edit
@4justman you're right, I'll change my description

Answer (score 0):

Try using a helper class like this:

```
{
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = DBHelper.getSession();

        // begin of different part  
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Table.class);
        if(filters!=null)
            createFilter(criteria, filters, null,null);                 
        long count=(long)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
        this.setRowCount((int) count);
        // end of different part

        DBHelper.commit(session);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        DBHelper.rollback(session);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DBHelper.close(session);
    }
}

// Helper Class

class DBHelper{
    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException{   
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session;
    }

    public static void rollback(Session session) throws HibernateException{
        if(session.getTransaction()!=null)
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public static void commit(Session session) throws HibernateException{
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static void close(Session session){
        if(session!=null){
            try{
                session.flush();
                session.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not really shorter

Comment: The answer was only for _"I want to reuse block of java code"_